# How to use @material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I am studying the documentation Material-UI useScrollTrigger and trying to apply it to Next to repeat the Elevate App Bar.

https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/#usescrolltrigger-options-trigger

```
import React from "react";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import useScrollTrigger from "@material-ui/core/useScrollTrigger";

interface Props {
  children: React.ReactElement;
}

function ElevationScroll(props: Props) {
  const children = props;
  const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
    disableHysteresis: true,
    threshold: 0
  });

  return React.cloneElement(children, {
    elevation: trigger ? 4 : 0
  });
}

export default class HeaderAppBar {
  render() {
    return (
      <ElevationScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar />
      </ElevationScroll {...props}>
    );
  }
}
```

But I get the error `ReferenceError: props is not defined`. Please help solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HeaderAppBar is a class component, so you need to refer to this.props instead of just props.

Also, you’ll need to destructure children off of props in ElevationScroll:

`const { children } = props`